# How to create an offer for an existing ASIN on Amazon?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-advertising-api, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am looking for creating an offer by having the ASIN, and the inventory options (SKU, quantity, price etc).

We already have access to the Amazon SP API:

```
const SellingPartnerAPI = require('amazon-sp-api');

const TOKEN = '...';

(async () => {
    try {
        let sellingPartner = new SellingPartnerAPI({
          region: "eu",
          refresh_token: TOKEN
        });

        const createOffer = async (options) => {
            // ... This needs to be implemented
        }

        let res = await createOffer({
            asin: ...,
            sku: ...,
            quantity: ...,
            price: ...
        });
        console.log(res);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
})()
```

Amazon Support was not very helpful, but they suggested we should use the [Listings endpoints](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-models/tree/main/models/listings-items-api-model), however I still find it rather confusing.

What is the right way to create the offer for a given ASIN and the inventory data?